# Snapshot Transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to perform a delete and an insert inside a snapshot transaction.

The way I'm doing it:

```
set transaction isolation level snapshot

begin transaction
    Delete from tbl_test
    Insert into tbl_test select * from tbl_source
commit transaction
```

I want that if I query the table tbl_test, during the transaction, the result to be as before the transaction. After I hit commit, I want the new data to be available. 
What happens is that the data inside the table has the initial value until the delete finishes. When the insert begins the snapshot is erased and the new data is available.

Any clues how to solve this?

Comment: You want to place a select statement between Delete and Insert in the same transaction and this select statement should return all the records that were available before starting the transaction.

Comment: Have you enabled `ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION` on that database?

Comment: See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcbchxcb(v=vs.100).aspx (first statement)

Comment: @Romil this functionality is made. After the delete, the table has the same behaviour as the initial one. But, when the insert starts, quering the table returns the new data.

Comment: @thecoon Yes I have enabled the option on the database

Comment: what is the isolation level when you execute Select statement on tbl_test table in another session. I am not able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Romil I used for the select READCOMMITTED hints or no hint

Comment: I think you should check  isolation level where you are firing Select statement. I am not able to reproduce this because Select is not completed till the transaction is not over.